# RelativeLayout View to right of TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I got following simple Layout. The problem can be reproduced in the android studio designer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/x"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_small"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_small"
    android:text="@string/long_string"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/y"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/x"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/x"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This layout works fine if the text length of the textview is short. The checkbox is placed on the right of the textview. But if the text gets long and even wraps maybe, then the checkbox is pushed out of the view. It is not visible anymore. I would like that the checkbox is always visible on the right of the textview even, if it fills the whole width of the screen.

I tried to rewrite the layout with a LinearLayout which doesn't work either.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/x"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_small"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_small"
    android:text="@string/long_string"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/y"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Do you know a trick to to achieve this with relative layout? I would somehow expect this behaviour from relative layout by default. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working for me: make checkBox alignParentRight and make TextView toLeftOf it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/x"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/y"
        android:text="This is very-very-very looooooooooooong stringgggg, very-very, long-long"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/y"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Edit.** You can include this Relative Layout into other (parent) layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="left">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/x"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/y"
            android:text="this is veryyyyy yyyyyyyyyy yyyyyy yyy loooooo oooooooo ooon nnggggg gggg striiii iiiiin gggggg ggggg ggggggg ggg"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/y"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />    

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

It's also working. If you put android:gravity="left" into Relative layout, it will locate its content on the left side.

Comment: I am aware of that possibility, but as i asked i want the checkbox to be on the right of the textview not on the parent right, because this layout doesnt' work well on tablets with a large screen. Because with short strings the two elements would be too much separated.

Comment: Ok, you can take this relative layout as separate item (view) and include it in your parent layout/s.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Could you clarify? Including this layout in a parent view, does not change any behaviour :)

Comment: Assuming you have parent layout named l1 and there you wish text and checkbox to be included in. Now you have relative layout (r2), which contains text and checkbox in abovementioned way. Now, instead of including text and checkbox in layout l1, you include them in r2 layout, and then just include r2 in l1. Visually it's the same, but you have wanted behaviour.

Comment: In code of your question, include r2 layout from my prevous comment in your top Relative layout

Comment: First i thought assume it works by wrapping. But when you wrap it then, the layout stays right aligned if the string is short. But the layout should be left aligned. You can check it if, you set a short text.

Comment: Ok, it's really strange for me, but if you add android:gravity="left" into Relative layout (r2) it will work how you wish

Comment: great! Thanks ;) maybe you want to edit that in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

One way out would be to put the textview and checkbox in a linear layout with orientation horizontal. Set width of checkbox to be whatever you want (a constant) and the width of textbox to be 0dp and layout_weight of 1.

Comment: Thanks, but this is basically the same like the other two answers. If i wanted that layout i'd take a relative layout with the checkbox align parent right.

Answer (score 1):

You should put the property layout_weight to make your views (TextView and Checkbox) have a deff space in the screen instead of use a hard value

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/x"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_small"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_small"
        android:text="@string/long_string"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/y"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       />

     </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks but this has basically the same effect as if i put the checkbox align parent right, and the textbox to the left of it. So the result is not satisfying on phones and tablets. I the text is short, then the checkbox is almost parent right but not to the right of the textview.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the desired layout is not possible by default. I tried to do this using RelativeLayout, LinearLayout and TableLayout. It is technically understandable that the these layout do not support that behaviour. The relative layout would have to explicitly respect the case that an element on the left or right is minimal visible inside the parent even it is placed to left or right. Another solution would be if the table layout would allow a column to consume the rest of the space but respects min width of other columns as well.

For my case i wrote a workaround. I used the initial relative layout of my question but set a max width to the textview using following calculation:

```
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    context.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int displayWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```

That guarantees the checkbox to be visible. I know the solution could be hardly possible in scenarios where the given layout is embedded in a more complex layout.